# why Bubble Sort linked list does not work?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a small project to give point password and list strongest ones but my sort algorithm does not work, any assistance appeciated.
I tried too many alternative solutions but still does not sort. I think it appears because of struct parts i found it on the forums its my first time to use this kind of struct types.

````
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define LSIZ 33 
#define RSIZ 10000 
typedef struct Node
{
    void* data;
    int score;
    struct Node* next;
}Node;

typedef struct 
{
    Node* head;
}Linked_List;

Linked_List* create_empty_list(void)
{
    Linked_List* new_head; 
    new_head = (Linked_List*)malloc(sizeof(Linked_List)); 
    new_head->head = NULL;
    
    return new_head;
}
    
Node* insert_end(Linked_List* list, void* data)
{
    Node* new_node;
    Node* temp;
    new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    new_node->data = (char*)data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if(list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = list->head;
        while(temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        
        temp->next = new_node;
    }
    return(list->head);
}
void SortList(Linked_List* list){
    Node *temp, *index=NULL;
    temp = list->head;
    int tmp;
        while(temp!=NULL){
            index = temp->next;
            while(index!=NULL){
                if(temp->score > index->score){
                    tmp = temp->score;
                    temp->score = index->score;
                    index->score = tmp;
                }
                index = index->next;
            }
            temp = temp->next;}}```
````

Comment: regarding statements like; `new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).  2) always check the returned value (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed")`  to output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred

Comment: regarding: `if(temp->score > index->score){
                    tmp = temp->score;
                    temp->score = index->score;
                    index->score = tmp;
                }`  this fails to swap the data pointed to by the field: `void data*;`

Comment: regarding: `new_node->data = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    new_node->data = (char*)data;`  the `malloc()` sets a pointer to somewhere in the `heap`.  The second statement overlays that pointer with the passed in parameter pointer.   The result is a memory leak.

Comment: regarding: `temp = temp->next;}}`  Please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   Treat `}` as a separate statement.

Comment: regarding; `new_node->data = (char*)data;`  since the `new_node->data` is a `void*` type, and the passed in parameter is a `void*` type, why cast the passed in parameter to `char*`?

Comment: OT:  since the purpose is to determine the strength of a password, why is there the implementation of a linked list?  Why not simply apply some criteria to the target password?

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: the function: `sortlist()` doesn't seem to be implementing a `bubble sort`.  Suggest using: [bubble sort algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/)  for an example of a bubble sort written in C